# Does firebase login use cookies in mobile device?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Recently i am working with a mobile authentication service and i want to know about the firebase authentication mechanism and did they use cookies for the authentication part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication passes information about the current user in the `Authorization` header and not in cookies. You can check this in the Network tab of your browser.